How to use default member initializer if `std::initializer_list` ctor exists in C++11?
Consider the following code:
#include <iostream>

struct A {
    A(int, int) {
        std::cout << "A::A(int, int)\n";
    }

    A(std::initializer_list<int>) {
        std::cout << "A::A(std::initializer_list<int>)\n";
    }
};

struct B {
    A a(1, 2); // compiler error
};

struct C {
    A a{1, 2}; // always call A::A(std::initializer_list<int>)
};

struct D {
    A a{A(1, 2)}; // always call A::A(int, int), how UgLy it is!
};

int main() {
    new B{};
    new C{};
    new D{};
}

Is there a better solution than A a{A(1, 2)};?

A a = A(1, 2); is possible too

A a = A(1, 2);. See Why can't member initializers use parentheses?

Also, this is not Most Vexing Parse. Standard explicitly say you can only use in-class initailiser with {} or =, () is not allowed to prevent vexing parsing.

As many before you, you've stumbled upon one of the issues with the "uniform" initialization. :P The constructors of std::vector blow up in the same way. The solution? Don't use {} everywhere, only use it when you want the initializer_list constructor. And to prevent narrowing you instead turn on the warnings.

I recommend using {} for construction everywhere, except when the class has a std::initializer_list — then use the {} carefully and use the () because you have to.

Tagged constructor also minimize issue with initializer_list.

IMO main problem is As API design. You should avoid design API which introduces clash between constructor with std::initializer_list and other constructors. std::vector has  this nasty problem. Since desire to have std::vector initialized with std::initializer_list was strong and need to maintain backward compatibility, we have this pitfall now.

The {...} triggers the initializer_list<T> "only" when the items in the list are all (convertible to) T. If the { } contains other values, it will not match, and try other costructors instead.

The default member initializer for the member should be a brace-or-equal-initializer. (Parentheses cannot be used since it could conflict with function declaration syntax in some situations.)
Thus, the member can be initialized in one of the two ways:

Using an equal-initializer:
struct B {
   A a = A(1, 2);
};


Using the member initializer list in the constructor:
struct B {
   A a;
   B(): a(1, 2) {}
};



